# how can i fix these weird shades

Tags: texturing, shadows

started learning blender today i was following a tutorial but suddenly i realised i had some weird shades in the middle of donut.[image: this is the image u can see weird line in middle]
I followed the tutorial exactly like him but dosent has any lines like these (please explain me in simple terms how can fix this as i am a beginner)

Comment: maybe overlapping vertices, inner faces, inverted normals?

Comment: sorry but can u please explain i am not fimiliar with these terms as i started today

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/ (upload then share the link it will generate in the URL)

Comment: It looks like disconnected edges - try selecting the whole donut in edit mode then pressing M (merge) and selecting "by distance".

Comment: sorry you had to wait here is it:     https://pasteall.org/blend/1a91e183288e4360a1188562224f6c46

Comment: when i press m it dosent select mesh at back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, the "donut" is suffering from badly connected edges (or some not connected at all).

[image: Edge1]

The solution is to select the whole mesh in edit mode, press M and select "By Distance". You will have to increase the merge threshold in the operator panel that appears in the bottom left. I find a distance of .0004M is sufficient to connect your mesh edges.

[image: Edge2]

Final result:

[image: Edge3]

Comment: i dont know what i did but it worked thanks alot man god bless you